# IE6 - why the favicon does not work?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, favicon

I made a favicon for my website. Naturally, on IE I have some trouble :)

Why doesn't this work?

```
<link rel="icon" href="./img/iconcab.ico" />
```

Dunno. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: what is the absolute URI? Are you using the right Content-Type? Did you save it out properly?

Comment: Why 'naturally'? Didn't IE introduce favicons?

Comment: "naturally" because we have more difficulty getting IE to behave right than we do any other browser. Especially IE 6.

Comment: yeah, i have problems ONLY on IE. The path it's correct because i can see it on other browser. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> p.s. i've add the <link> on <body>

Comment: I can't believe anyone is still developing for IE6. No offence! But if you don't develop for chineese market than I just can't understand it - http://www.ie6countdown.com/ (btw it's a microsoft site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember dealing with favicons before and I'm pretty sure IE6 REQUIRES the icon file to be called favicon.ico and be placed in the root directory of your website (or at least in the same directory of the page you're trying to access). I may be remembering it wrong but it could be worth a try.

Comment: uhm no, i don't think so. Just watch (as random example) http://www.discogs.com/. You can see <link rel="icon" href="http://s.dsimg.com/images/record16.ico" /> , but it works (i can see that icon on IE6)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the type `type="image/ico"`

Does it work with other browser?

Is the path correct?

Comment: yes! it works with chrome, firefox, ecc... so the path it's correct. If i add type="image/ico" it doesnt change.

Answer (score 0):

ie6 needs a favicon to be a true icon file. not a png pretending to be an icon.
use irfanview to make it inta a real icon, 16x16

also, it needs to be referenced within the same dir or root dir.

favicons used to give me hell with ie6.

usually they only showed up after bookmarking or dumping the entire cache.